# How to sum numbers with formats like N.NNNN,NN in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Well, long story short. I'm looking for a way to sum numbers with comma for decimals and thousand seperator.

Currently, I'm trying to format the number with

```
sumamount += parseFloat(this.value.replace(/,/g,''));
```

it sill not working correctly.

Is there another way then removing the dot, replacing `,` with `.` and in the end reversing the change again? Thank you very much!

so, this is working, but... not really pretty nor performant, is it?

```
sumamount += parseFloat(this.value.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'));
```

Comment: An example would be great

Comment: No, there's no other way. JS has no built-in way to parse numbers like this.

Comment: What you have done is the right way of doing it. Can't get simpler than that. It can be a pain parsing Euro format sometimes.

Comment: Maybe you wanna checkout https://currency.js.org/

Comment: thank you very much guys! I will check out currency.js too. It seemed to be a bit too complicated to be "correct" at first glance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *have* to do ugly string operations to convert a number-like string like this to Float/Number. To 'reverse the change' you may want to try `Number.toLocaleString` for your own locale ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) for that).

```js
const someValue = "200.204,23";
const toNumber = Number(someValue.split(".").join("").split(",").join("."));
console.log(toNumber);
console.log(toNumber.toLocaleString("NL-nl"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

A clean way would be to use [currency.js](https://github.com/scurker/currency.js) (1.1kB Gziped)

```
const FORMAT = { separator: '.', decimal: ',' };

const v1 = currency('140.504,99', FORMAT);
const v2 = currency('24.207,56', FORMAT);
```

then,

```
v1.add(v2)
```

Output

```
164712.55
```

Or,

```
v1.add(v2).format()
```

gives

```
164.712,55
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also convert the numbers into their original formats then do what ever you wish to do with them. Like this:

```
let rev = (a)=>
{
    // r is the real number
    let r = 0;

    a = a.split(",").reverse();

    for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        r += Number(a[i]) * Math.pow(1000,i);
    }

    return r;
}

let sum = (a,b)=>
{
    return (rev(a) + rev(b));
}

console.log(sum("2,100","1,000.10")); //3100.1
```